# Angular UI-router force redirect before ajax finishes

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i’m looking to do a redirect based on authentication.  If a user is trying to hit `/dashboard`, it want to check to see if they are logged in first before ever attempting to switch to that route. If they aren’t authenticated, they go to `/login`.  Assuming I have a service that checks if they are logged in (via ajax), this is what i currently have:

```
var app = angular.module('someApp', [
  'ui.router'
]);

app.config([
  '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)
  {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard/:collectionId',
      templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/index.jade',
      controller: 'DashboardController'
    })
  }
]);

app.run([
  '$rootScope', '$location', 'loginFactory', 
  function($rootScope, $location, loginFactory)
  {
    $rootScope
    .$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
    {
      if (toState.name == 'dashboard')
      {
        loginFactory.isLogged().success(function(data)
        {
          if (!data)
          {
            e.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
]);

app.factory('loginFactory', [
  '$http', '$location',
  function($http, $location)
  {
    return {
      isLogged: function()
      {
          // assume i made this sleep for 5 seconds
          return $http.get('/auth/loggedin'); 
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

However, if i were to throw a sleep of 5 seconds on my endpoint, then the user will hit the `/dashboard` page and sit there for 5 seconds until they get redirected back to `/login`.  Any thoughts on how I can prevent them from moving forward to `/dashboard` until `loginFactory.isLogged()` successfully tells them they are done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your route in this way :

```
 $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard/:collectionId',
      templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/index.jade',
      controller: 'DashboardController',
      resolve: {
                // assuming your loginfactory is preloaded
            login: function(loginFactory){
                return loginFactory.isLogged();
            }
        },
    })
```

This will force the router change to happen only when all the dependencies are resolved

For more info you can refer [this](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)

Comment: That's the winner!  Thanks!   Also, helpful resource for other people: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec